# z-index between Children and Parents

Tags: css, z-index

I'm having problems working out the z-index order for an application we're working on, i have two root parents, a nav bar and a map, and one child, the map tooltip. The navbar should be visible above the map, so it has a higher z-index, but the problems is to make the tooltip in the map container to be displayed over the sidebar as well, a bit hard to explain, so you can visualize the case on http://jsbin.com/afakak/2/edit#javascript,html,live :

```
 <div id="nav-bar">
    The nav bar
  </div>

  <div id="map-container">
      This is the map container
      <div id="tooltip">
            This is the Tooltip
      </div>
  </div>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you remove the `z-index` from the `map-container`, and change it to `position: absolute`, and add `position: absolute` to the tooltip, the stack order seems to be fine:
http://jsbin.com/qaquxiyufa/1/edit?html,output
Just I do not understand why...
(And I guess this is not acceptable for you...)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If `#map-container` is positioned (i.e. not static), this is not possible, because of the way z-index is compared:

`body` (or any other positioned parent element) is the reference for both `#map-container` and `#nav-bar`. Any `z-index` you give them is calculated in respect to the parent element. So the one of the 2 elements with the higher z-index will be rendered above the other one and all its child elements. Z-index of `#tooltip` will only be compared with other children of `#map-container`.

You could do as Nacho said and statically position `#map-container`. You can simulate fixed positioning via Javascript, if you like.

If you cannot do that, you need to change your markup, so that `#nav-bar` and `#tooltip` have a common positioned parent element. Either move `#nav-bar` inside `#map-container`, or `#tooltip` out of it.

Answer (score 2):

Below solution should work but I don't know if you have a requirement like keeping `nav-bar` outside `map-container`. If so I don't think that there is a workaround for that.

CSS:

```
#tooltip-helper{
    position:relative;
    /*below properties are to demonstrate the helper*/
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    background-color:green;
    top:200px;
    left:200px;
}

#tooltip
{
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;/*this is just to make sure helper is visible*/
    left:-100px;/*this is to center the tooltip*/
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: yellow;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: 15;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="map-container">
    <div id="nav-bar">
      The nav bar
    </div>
    This is the map container
    <div id="tooltip-helper">
          <div id="tooltip">This is the Tooltip</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If, in the real page, the `tooltip` has to be shown only on hovering the map container, you could just change dynamically its z-index like so:

```
#map-container:hover
{
    z-index: 16
}
```

Otherwise you need to change the position of the `tooltip` so that the `nav-bar` doesn't overlap it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to absolutely position `nav-bar` and `tooltip` (otherwise z-index won't be taken in account), and maintain `map-container` static positioned

```
#map-container{
    ...
    position: static;
    ...
}

#nav-bar{
    ...
    position: absolute;
}

#tooltip{
    ...
    position: absolute
}
```

Comment: I cannot find `tooltip` in your page. Did you change it to absolute position?

Comment: but i need to keep the #map-container as fixed since it's a map occupying the whole page, check http://41.32.148.178:82/#!search=KFC%2F0%2F0%2F0%2F%2F

Comment: It's almost impossible the way it is... you'll need to wrap the panel within mapcontainer. Or change ALL the styles in your page again

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way you can do this with a `position: fixed` on the `#map-container` is to restructure your tool tips to display outside the `#map-container.` So on click of the icon "inside" the map container, the tool-tip itself is displayed above both (with a proper `z-index` set).

```
 <div id="nav-bar">
    The nav bar
  </div>

  <div id="map-container">
      This is the map container
  </div>

  <div id="tooltip">
      This is the Tooltip
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After going through, your codes, i noticed this.

```
 #tooltip{
background-color: yellow;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
color: black;
padding: 10px;
z-index: 15;
    }
```

Your #tooltip has a z-index, but it's not positioned. Z-index property will only work if it's has one of the position property value. And considering you want the tooltip to stand out, you should use the absolute position value like this.

```
 #tooltip{
position: absolute;
background-color: yellow;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
color: black;
padding: 10px;
z-index: 15;
 }
```

HTML

```
<div id="map-container">
<div id="nav-bar">
The nav bar
    </div>
  This is the map container
  <div id="tooltip">
        This is the Tooltip
  </div>
        </div>
```

This keeps the #tooltip on top....

Answer (score 0):

For future readers with similar problems -
If your conflicting child items are `position: fixed`, consider setting the height of the parent containers to 0px, and then shifting any parent background display settings onto a mutual grandparent of the conflicting children.

This solved my analogous delimma.