# z-index not working with 2 divs with Background images

Tags: css, z-index

I am working on an Background Ad-System and my z-index isn't working.

```
#page
{
    width: 1100px;
    margin: 100px 0px 0px -550px;
    min-height: 906px;
    background-color: #fff;
    left: 50%;
    cursor: auto;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

#adGfwADS
{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 1050px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: #000; background-image: url(http://crazysportz.de/1.jpg); background-position: 50% 0px;
}
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z6nKv/1/).

(Make the right col bigger to see the image and divs better)

Comment: What is not working? You need to describe your problem.

Comment: And please post code.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573686/z-index-between-children-and-parents

Comment: Your question is unclear, the layering appears to be working ok, do you just want to be able to see the right side of the image? If so just set decrease the `#page` width.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. the wrong div is up... The Code stand at jsfiddle and show at z-index.

```
#page
{
    width: 1100px;
    margin: 100px 0px 0px -550px;
    min-height: 906px;
    background-color: #fff;
    left: 50%;
    cursor: auto;
    position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
}

#adGfwADS
{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 1050px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
        z-index: 10;
    background-color: #000; background-image: url(http://crazysportz.de/1.jpg);     background-position: 50% 0px;
}

<div id="dimensions">
    <div id="adGfwADS" class="adGfwADS" url="http://google.de">
    <div id="page">blupp</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The div id="page" will show but this is wrong then z-index is lower as from adGfwAds and i use position to use z-index but z-index work not =(