# How to avoid Z-index of the parent div?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I want to avoid parent `div` z-index. Is it possible with any plugin?

```
<div id="1"> 
  <div id="2"></div>
</div>
```

`div` with `id` `1` = 950 of z-index

`div` with `id` `2` = 1 of z-index but on a click event it's equal to 9999 of z-index.

And i have a popup (`exposemask`) equal to 9998 of z-index.

What I want to do is to show `div` with `id` `2` when popup is active. However, `div` with `id` `1` overrides its z-index. Because it's a parent of the `div` with `id` `2` and I shouldn't change the z-index of `div` with `id` `1`.

Comment: No it's not possible, and if you keep the right order in your DOM you should (almost) never have to use z-index at all.

Comment: Hmm, is'it possible to make div id 2 as a popup in that case, so it will be without any parent div on a click event?

Comment: @John you could technically move it out of the parent...but why not place it outside of the parent in the first place?

Comment: Yes I can technicall do it. But the thing is that div id 2 is a part of zend framework. (And div id 1 is a part of my own framework) Which is all within the div 2. If I il move div 2 outise the div id 1 I will break alot of stuff. It's a last thing what I want to do in that case.

Comment: what happens if you have a `<div id="div3"></div>` somewhere else, and then when the popup is active, you do `<script>$("#div3").html("div#2").html());</script>` I mean, this would show the contents of the div#3. This might not require you to move anything, so whenever you call the popup, this call would update the contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, **you can't use numbers as css selectors** follow the
    [css grammar](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html#scanner)

**If parent doesn't need a z-index, you can do:**

What if you don't give a z-index to the parent div? But just give a negative z-index value to your child element, so it's hidden 'behind' the parent:

```
z-index: -1;
```

and whenever the popup is active, you will set a positive(higher z-index as the popup) z-index to the child element:

```
$('#div2').css('z-index', '2');
```

### [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/yD7Wr/1)

**If your parent always needs a z-index(If this parent element needs to go over a other element with a z-index for example) then it's not possible:**

It's not possible. As stated in this topic: [z-index between Children and Parents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573686/z-index-between-children-and-parents)

> All child element z-index is calculated in respect to the parent
>   element. So the one of the 2 elements with the higher z-index will be
>   rendered above the other one and all its child elements.

You can however get the child element out of the parent element.

---

I would also suggest you to just increase the z-index by 1 when neccesary and not use big numbers as 99999. With the big numbers you would not know how much z-indexes you have used.

Comment: thx, I know all this stuff. It's just like I'm looking for any chance if it's still possible somehow. Any hack or so. I know, sounds silly, but sometimes things make us to do a crazy shit ;{

Comment: I see. well check my update, i've tryed to make a workaround. However this only work when you parent element does not contain the z-index property.

Comment: Yes, it's a good idea. But not in my case. I can't leave my parent div without positive z-index. Thx anyway. I think I ve found an answer. I will need 2 override my own framework with some minor changes. This will give me a chance to move div id 2 out of the parent div id 1. I was hoping i can avoid it somehow.