# z-index not working properly?

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have the HTML:

```
<div class="arrow" id="link1">
    <img class="bellow" src="bottom.jpg" width="305" height="229" />
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.arrow {
  display: block;
  width: 305px;
  height: 229px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(top.png);
}

#link1 {
  background-position: 0 458PX;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
}

#link1:hover {
  background-position: 0 229px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
}

.bellow {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}
```

But the `background-image` is not showing up on top of the bottom.jpg what is wrong with the z-index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> body (or any other positioned parent element) is the reference for
> both the child and and parent element

source: [z-index between Children and Parents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573686/z-index-between-children-and-parents)

This means the `z-index` on your parent also applies to the child element. Where the child element(image) will also take `z-index: 10;`. With the parent and child both have a  `z-index` of 10, the child will actually be rendered over the parent.

To fix this **you should not even give a `z-index` to the parent**, but only to the child(the image):

```
.bellow {
    z-index: -1;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Where the image will have a lower value as the default value, thus will be underneath its parent.

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kz8ey/)

Comment: I should note that this *only* works if the z-index is never defined on the parent. Defining a z-index on the parent division (even a negative one) will cause it to stop working.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot position an element inside a parent element to be *behind* that parent element.

Consider an HTML structure like so:

```
<div class="level-1">
    <div class="level-2">
        <div class="level-3"></div>
        <div class="level-3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="level-2">
        <div class="level-3"></div>
        <div class="level-3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="level-1">
    <div class="level-2">
        <div class="level-3"></div>
        <div class="level-3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="level-2">
        <div class="level-3"></div>
        <div class="level-3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've conveniently named each division with a level-class to easier understand.

Z-indexing works by applying that z-index to other elements within each parent. So being on the root element, the z-index for each level-1 division would *only* apply to other level-1 divisions. Just like a level-2 index would only apply to another level-2 index, and the same with a level-3 index.

So indexing from inside out: the level-3 indices would be ordered *first* under each of their parents. Note that their z-index would **not** apply to other level-3 elements in other parents, only other elements under the *same* parent. Once ordering of those level-3 elements is done, they are placed into their level-2 parent. At that point, the level-2 elements get ordered based on their indices relative to their parent, and then placed into their parent the same way the level-3 elements were, and then the level-1 elements are done.

---

So the way your HTML structure is set up, with an image inside of a division, that image cannot appear underneath its parent. Structurally, that doesn't make sense anyways. A child is *meant* to be contained within a parent, it should never *stack* with its parent. If you really want to place the image behind the division, it should be place *outside* of the parent and positioned accordingly.

Having said that, there *is* a bit of a [hackish workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806421/css-parent-element-to-appear-above-child), but it requires removing the `position: absolute` from the parent division and using a negative z-index.

Answer (score 0):

`z-index` works with `absolute/fixed/relative` positions only.

Write:

```
.arrow{position:relative;}
```

Also,

Remove `image` out of div.

It should work.

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/HQcdh/1/)

Comment: What and change it to a div with a background-image?